# Dart/Flutter. Как получить ключ из массива?

Tags: flutter, dart

Всем привет, в общем такая проблема.
Есть класс:

```
class ExampleTest {
  String text;
  Map<String, bool> options;

  ExampleTest({
    this.text,
    this.options,
  });
}
```

На его основе есть массив:

```
List<ExampleTest> array = [
      ExampleTest(
        text: 'Title 1',
        options: {'Red': true, 'White': false, 'Black': false, 'Green': false},
      ),
    ];
```

Естественно, экземпляров ExampleTest в массиве будет много, но не суть. Нужно дорваться до каждого ключа options, чтобы вывести в виджет Text('').
Например:
Text(array[0].text) вывидет 'Title 1', это понятно.
Text(array[0].options.keys.first) вывидет 'Red', last вместо first вывидет последний ('Green'). Это всё понятно. А вот как в виджет Текст вывести второй и третий ключ?
Я уже что только не пробовал с этими кавычками, скобками и т.д. Гулёж приводит к примерам с простенькими колекциями. В общем, где-то вокруг да около хожу, туплю на ровном месте.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще его можно вывести так: `Text(array[0].options.keys.toList()[2])`, так как `keys` это [Iterable](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.1/dart-core/Iterable-class.html).

Но вы не правильно используете [Map](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.1/dart-core/Map-class.html). Вы должны по ключу получать значение (пример: `array[0].options['Black']` даст `false`).

Если вам нужно получить и ключ, и значение, то лучше сделать класс и поместить его в `List`:

```
class Options {
  Options(
    this.key,
    this.value,
  );

  final String key;
  final bool value;
}

class ExampleTest {
  ExampleTest({
    this.text,
    this.options,
  });

  final String text;
  final List<Options> options;
}

List<ExampleTest> array = [
    ExampleTest(text: 'Title 1', options: <Options>[
      Options('Red', true),
      Options('White', false),
      Options('Black', false),
      Options('Green', false),
    ]),
    ExampleTest(text: 'ExampleTest 2', options: <Options>[
      Options('Red', false),
      Options('Green', false),
      Options('Black', false),
    ]),
  ];
```

И использовать так:

```
Text(array[0].options[2].key);
Text(array[0].options[2].value);
```

Comment: Ругается в 'options: '

Comment: @MeierLink да извините писал код прям тут, не заметил ошибок. Сейчас код полностью рабочий.